# NewConnectionError when trying to install Tensorflow on Windows 10 with python 3.5

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently trying to install tensorflow with Python 3.5 and I am running into a new connection error. I am trying to follow the install guide from tensorflow. Has anyone seen this issue before and figured out a solution? Thanks.

```
c:\>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002245E6C30F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002245E6D0470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002245E6D05C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002245E6D0710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002245E6D0860>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',)': /simple/tensorflow/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: I would figure that it's something temporary to do with network issues, have you tried to do the same from another computer?

Comment: I had similar issues and solved it by using Intel's version of Python 3.5 with all scientific packages included. After installing this you can simply do `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu` and it will probably work

Comment: @OferSadan I have not been able to try on another machine at this time. I plan to try another machine and even network when I am able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not definitive, but I would suggest a few actions:

1. Consider testing from another machine on the same network, or even a different network, to test for actual network issues you might have.
2. This might be a temporary issue with the server, try again later.
3. Try to install some other package with pip, to rule out possible problems with your pip itself
4. Installing tensorflow doesn't have to be done with pip, you can either follow [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) to install via anaconda, or [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) to install tensorflow from source (however, source installations are not officially supported on windows)

Comment: it was a network error.  tried a different network and it worked fine.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the connection was blocked by Kaspersky. Temporary switching it off solved my issue.